# Will there be a boot selection screen after uninstalling WUBI installed Ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, uninstall, bootloader

I'd like to know if uninstalling Ubuntu via "Programs and Features" on Windows 7 or Vista would also *remove the boot entries* that had once been created during installation, and would it thereafter prevent the OS selection screen at Windows startup (usually after BIOS) which asks to select either from Windows or Ubuntu?

I installed through WUBI on Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

If windows is the only OS that remains i expect the screen will no longer appear since it has no purpose, otherwise it might just remove its own entry and thats it.